# How to include decimal in calculation

Tags: vba, excel

this is a question regarding another post.

I wrote a code to do the following:

It will take a number x and then find every number in the data set that is 14, 28, 42, 56 apart and so on.
The issue I am having with my original code shown below is that its does not account for those values that are 13.99 or 13.55 apart. Not sure how to add in the criteria to account for this. My code works for whole numbers but not for decimals:

```
Sub GetPairs()
  Dim x, z As Single
  Dim lastRow, pasterow As Single
  Dim testMass, nomMass As Single
  Dim lastValue As Long
  Dim colCounter As Long
   Dim lookUpRange As Range
    lastRow = Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    lastValue = Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Value
    Set lookUpRange = Worksheets(1).Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
  pasterow = 2
  For x = 2 To lastRow
    nomMass = Cells(x, 2).Value
    colCounter = 3
    For z = Round((nomMass + 14), 0) To Round((lastValue + 14), 0) Step 14
        If Found(lookUpRange, z) Then
            'found
           Worksheets(1).Cells(x, colCounter) = z
            colCounter = colCounter + 1
        End If
    Next z
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the step up function to step up a btw (13.5-14)? Does the step up function have to be set as a whole number?

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in Round() function. It takes two arguments: the number (or cell, or variable) to be rounded, and the degree of precision.

To round 13.55 or 13.99 to 14, use precision of zero. So, if you round the value in cell F23, it would look like: =Round(F23, 0)

Olivia, in answer to your question about step values: Yes, you can use values that are not whole numbers (for example: Step .1 is fine) in your For loops but I am pretty sure you can't use a range (for example: Step .1 to .5 not allowed).

Comment: Thanks Anthony, but I want to have the decimal values included in my final result. As my code reads now I exclude all values that are not a perfect multiple of 14.